# How to customize Hint Font.Size?

Tags: delphi, hint, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a Delphi 10.4.2 32-bit VCL application on Windows 10, I am trying to customize the Hint `Font.Size`:

```pascal
type
  TExHint = class(THintWindow)
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;
    
var
  Form1: TForm1;
    
implementation
    
{$R *.dfm}
    
constructor TExHint.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  with Canvas.Font do
  begin
    //Name  := 'Verdana';
    Size  := 15;
    //Style := [fsBold, fsItalic];
  end;
end;
    
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HintWindowClass  := TExHint;
end;
```

But it does not work.

How can I customize the Hint `Font.Size` of my application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's much easier than this.

Just set the [`Screen.HintFont`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.HintFont) property:

```pascal
procedure TForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.HintFont.Size := 20;
end;
```

[image: Screenshot of hint with large font]

or even

[image: Even larger font size]

or

[image: Even larger]

Comment: It works - but there's a huge gap between the lines of a multi-line hint: https://i.imgur.com/npUF4dD.png

Comment: @user1580348: I think it looks good: https://privat.rejbrand.se/hintsize2ln.png. I suspect you have two line breaks (#13#10#13#10) instead of only one (#13#10).

Comment: You are right. The CnPack Hint-Editor Wizard seems to add an additional `#13#10` when creating a multi-line Hint!